# Can't connect to the internet after installation in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I recently installed arch on my system, and after finishing the installation process and rebooting I tried to install some packages, but I get `Failed retrieving file... Could not resolve hostname` error. I also tried pinging but I got a `Temporary failure in name resolution` error. I think that this is because the internet. I've already tried to use `nmcli`, but it didn't work. When I tried `dhcpcd` it said `command not found`. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: While network configuration can be complex, you should not use Arch if you need to ask such questions. "Temporary failure in name resolution" means that your name resolution is not set up correctly. I believe Arch uses `systemd-resolved`, which you will have to troubleshoot. DHCP might also be broken, but `dhcpd` is the DHCP server; you need to check if the client exists and what errors, if any, it reports. To improve your question, you could say what precisely you did with `nmcli`.

Comment: To add to what @berndbausch said, be aware that for *any* OS (operating system), initial OS setup over WiFi is often problematic. It is best to install and configure the base system with a wired ethernet connection, and only switch to WiFi _after_ you have installed and configured the entire WiFi subsystem for the OS.

Comment: How did you configure networking during the installation process? E.g. did you install NetworkManager? What network hardware does your host have? Wireless card? Ethernet? What is the output of a plain `nmcli`? (This is only relevant if you chose NetworkManager to configure and manage networking). Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/646324/edit) your question to add further information.